# How to debug sorting of Json in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to troubleshoot some column position in my app and need to be able to see what the sorted column definition looks like. I get the column definition from my API and then i sort them but i would also like to log the sorted list / Array to my console to make sure it is correct.
Where and how could I access the sorted list in my below code ?

```
fetchColumnsAgGrid(guid: string): Observable<IGridColumnAgGrid[]> {
        return this.api.get({endpoint: `/sample/getgrid/${guid}`, useAuthUrl: false})
            .pipe(
                map((res: any) => {
                    console.log(res)
                    return res.Data && res.Data.map((column) => {
                        return GridColumnsService.adaptAgGridColumn(column);
                    }).sort((a, b) => {
                        if (a.position < b.position) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        if (a.position > b.position) {
                            return 1;
                        }
                        return 0;
                    });
                }),
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add tap right after your sort map ends.

```
fetchColumnsAgGrid(guid: string): Observable<IGridColumnAgGrid[]> {
        return this.api.get({endpoint: `/sample/getgrid/${guid}`, useAuthUrl: false})
            .pipe(
                map((res: any) => {
                    console.log(res)
                    return res.Data && res.Data.map((column) => {
                        return GridColumnsService.adaptAgGridColumn(column);
                    }).sort((a, b) => {
                        if (a.position < b.position) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        if (a.position > b.position) {
                            return 1;
                        }
                        return 0;
                    });
                }),
                //Here
                tap((res: any) => console.log(res))
            );
    }
```